# What word/phobia refers to the fear that ceilings will fall on you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

What word/phobia refers to the fear that ceilings will fall on you?

Example:

> John's ______ made him decide to live in a bungalow, because he thinks one ceiling falling on him would not be sufficient to kill him, but two or more would.

Comment: I'm not convinced the ancient Greeks believed in an afterlife as per Xtians & Muslims "going to heaven". So I could easily believe that [Uranophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranophobia) originally applied to people who didn't like having "the heavens" always oppressively above them. (Perhaps ***uranophobes*** were the first people to be told *Don't look so worried! [The sky won't fall in!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+sky+won%27t+fall+in%22)* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  http://www.ancient.eu/article/29/

Comment: @Cathy Gartaganis: Exactly! They believed *the continued existence of the dead depended on their constant remembrance by the living*. For the most part, the dead went into permanent sleep in the underworld - they didn't float up to the sky to collect their harps and virgins.

Comment: Chicken little syndrome? A very narrow form of *barophobia*? It is a *specific phobia*, for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you Google for "[ceiling phobia](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ceiling%20phobia)," a condition called *[altocelarophobia](http://altocelarophobia.yolasite.com/)* seems to be a thing:

> **alto-** (*high*) **celaro-** (*ceiling*) **phobia** (*irrational fear*)
>
> an irrational fear of high ceilings

So, by analogy:

> **obcursu-** (*falling*) **celaro-** (*ceiling*) **phobia**

Behold *obcursucelarophobia*: an irrational fear of falling ceilings.

Answer (score 1):

May be not exactly what you are looking for, but **[Anablephobia](http://common-phobias.com/anable/phobia.htm)** is some what related.

Comment: You probably want to include the definition for anablephobia in your answer as well as cite the source...just in case the link fails in the future.